# How To Get Value From Form To Program.CS(For Example Current Form Name)?

Tags: c#, forms, windows

I'm really interest how can i get my variable value like form name or form text in program.cs!
For Example I Have This Code In My Form

```
     public partial class Main : Form
    {
        private string FormLocation = null;
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FormLocation = this.Name;    //<==== Important
        }
}
```

Now i Just Want The **FormLocation** Value in Program.CS for Registering All User Activity's, i need to know in which form the user exited with form close button
As My Code in Program.cs Is :

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    static void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DialogResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure To Exit?", "ExitConfirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel))
        {
         ActivityRegistration(UserId, FormLocation); //<===== Important
             if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.MessageLoop)
               {
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
               }
             else
               {
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
               }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Attention, I Do NOT want to use form events.i want unique method in program.cs to do the job for all forms...as you can see in my example second part of code. i do wrote an event for all kind of application exiting

Comment: You don't want to track form closing event for every form?

Comment: My problem is EXACTLLY :
HOW TO WRITE AN EVENT IN PROGRAM.CS TO RECOGNIZE ALL FORMS WHEN THEY GO TO CLOSE BY FormCloseButton

Comment: @Hassan Nisar, Belive me ,I Really Want to.

Comment: @user3823980, what you're asking doesn't make sense.  How would defining an event in the `Program` class help?  If `Program` wants to react to something happening then it needs to HANDLE and event, not RAISE one.  If you want to know when something happens in a form then that form has to raise the event, plain and simple.  You can create some sort of form manager class and have all your form creation and access go through there but what you're suggesting would be pure magic.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney:
So you can see this magic in our friends answer down here as ANSWER1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Track `FormClosing` event of form.

On Application Exit every form closing event is fired. Save the name of the form in the public `List<string>` accessible from `Program.cs`.

**Program.cs**:

```
static class Program
{
    static public List<string> lstClosedForms;
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);
        lstClosedForms = new List<string>();
        Application.Run(new Form1());           
    }

    static void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           if (DialogResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure To Exit?", "ExitConfirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel))
           {
                 ActivityRegistration(UserId, lstClosedForms); // 2nd argument changed to List<string>

                if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.MessageLoop)              
                      System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();               
                else               
                      System.Environment.Exit(1);               
            }
     }
}
```

**Form1**:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
    }

    void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Program.lstClosedForms.Add(this.Name);
    }
 }
```

**NOTE**: Modify the list whenever new Form is created.

Comment: Please Give me some Example Code, I can not understand how to do this
by the way. I don't want to use FormClosinng Event...
Attention: I Want one method in Program.cs to do the job auto for all forms

Comment: ActivityRegistration method would be changed in that case. Use a custom class to track information of each form.

Comment: static public List<string> lstClosedForms;
Why declare a List? Why don't use just a string?

Comment: `List<string>` to track number of forms. You could easily add/remove entries in it. For single `Form1` you don't need to either string or list because object could be accessible in the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot,Your answer was really useful.
I will be thankful if you just raise my question vote up.

Comment: I have just figured out that my answer is not right. I think I would prefer to delete it, until I sort it out or some other guy gives a valid answer.

Comment: Issue is to track individual form closing (that is without application Exit).